# Understanding a limit in standard Borel probability space

Tags: measure-theory

There is an exercise in lectures:

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a standard Borel probability space and $(B_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \Sigma$.

Show that
\begin{align*}
  μ(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n) = \lim_{N \to \infty} μ(\cup_{n
                    \leqslant N} B_n)
\end{align*}

I'm not sure where to start. My problem is that I'm confused about what the limit even means here. Would appreciate a hint or pointer on how to go about evaluating such limits ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The limit here is the usual limit of real sequences, note that for each $N$ $\mu(\bigcup_{n\le N} B_n) =: a_N$ is a real number in $[0,1]$ and you are asked to prove, that the sequence $(a_N)$ converges to $\mu(\bigcup_n B_n)$. To do so, one possibility is to write $\bigcup B_n$ as a disjoint union $\bigcup B_n = \biguplus C_n$ such that $\bigcup_{n\le N} B_n = \biguplus_{n\le N} C_n$ for each $N$? Can you guess how to find such $C_n$? Then you have 
$$ a_N = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\le N} B_n\right) = \mu\left(\biguplus_{n\le N} C_n\right) = \sum_{n\le N} \mu(C_n) $$
and 
$$ \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} B_n\right) = \mu\left(\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N} c_n\right) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \mu(C_n) $$
Can you prove convergence from here?

Comment: Okay, so $C_n = B_n \backslash \cup_{i=1}^{n-1} B_i$, so then $\lim a_N = \lim \sum_{n \leqslant N} \mu(C_n) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu(C_n)$ so we are done?

Comment: @user81204 Yes, we are. ${}{}$

Comment: Thanks for that. I should've known this.